# GSM signal strength measurements in android application always show 0

Tags: android

signal strength always show 0

This code is running without error but always showing signal strength is 0. I tried to run this code both on my emulator and my android device but it is showing signal strength 0.

please give detail description for getting correct signal strength of my mobile network and also of the code for getting of signal strength of other network in area if possible.

MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.termproject;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
 import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
 import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity 
 {
    TelephonyManager Tel;
    MyPhoneStateListener MyListener;
    private int signal;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     }

     @Override
               public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
     {
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
         return true;
     }
     class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener
     {
       int signal;
       @Override
       public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength)
       {
          super.onSignalStrengthsChanged(signalStrength);
          signal = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
       }
     }
     public void myaction(View v)
     {
        MyListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();
         Tel = ( TelephonyManager )getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
         Tel.listen(MyListener ,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTHS);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GSM signal strength is " +    String.valueOf(this.signal), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 }
```

Manifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.termproject"
     android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0" >

     <uses-sdk
         android:minSdkVersion="8"
         android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
     <!-- PERMISSIONS -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <!-- LICENSE PERMISSIONS -->    
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

    <!-- USES -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony"      android:required="false"/>
     <application
         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
             android:name=".MainActivity"
             android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
         </activity>
     </application>

 </manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" >

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         tools:context=".MainActivity" />
     <Button
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/button_send" 
         android:onClick="myaction"/>


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

This thread seems to identify your PhoneStateListener is not correct. Judging by your problem, it appears that you have a CDMA device so GSM will always return 0. Not sure what the expected behavior of the emulator is.

[Detecting when reception returns Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048986/detecting-when-reception-returns-android)

```
package com.piusvelte.wapdroid;

import static com.piusvelte.wapdroid.WapdroidService.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA;
import static android.telephony.NeighboringCellInfo.UNKNOWN_RSSI;
import android.telephony.CellLocation;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.SignalStrength;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

// PhoneStateListener for api >= 7
public class PhoneListenerApi7 extends PhoneStateListener {
        private WapdroidService mService;

        public PhoneListenerApi7(WapdroidService service) {
                mService = service;
        }

        public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
                // this also calls signalStrengthChanged, since signalStrengthChanged isn't reliable enough by itself
                mService.getCellInfo(location);
        }

        public void onSignalStrengthChanged(int asu) {
                // add cdma support, convert signal from gsm
                if ((mService.mTeleManager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) || (mService.mTeleManager.getPhoneType() == PHONE_TYPE_CDMA)) mService.signalStrengthChanged((asu > 0) && (asu != UNKNOWN_RSSI) ? (2 * asu - 113) : asu);
                else mService.release();
        }

        public void onSignalStrengthsChanged(SignalStrength signalStrength) {
                if (mService.mTeleManager.getPhoneType() == TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM) {
                        int asu = signalStrength.getGsmSignalStrength();
                        mService.signalStrengthChanged((asu > 0) && (asu != UNKNOWN_RSSI) ? (2 * asu - 113) : asu);
                }
                else if (mService.mTeleManager.getPhoneType() == PHONE_TYPE_CDMA) mService.signalStrengthChanged(signalStrength.getCdmaDbm() < signalStrength.getEvdoDbm() ? signalStrength.getCdmaDbm() : signalStrength.getEvdoDbm());
                else mService.release();
        }
}
```